# Laravel redirect won't execute but the page loads in preview (DevTools)

Tags: laravel, redirect, post

I am making a frontend post request to server (ajax using jquery), the controller is doing some logic but when trying to redirect, the front-end will not execute.

My code in controller:

```
return redirect('/home')
```

Home is a named route in `web.php`, but also there exists `example.com/home` url in case someone asks.

What is weird is that I can see `home` page being returned and rendered in `DevTools->Network Tab->XHR Preview` on that request.

I am suspecting that it is something to do with the post request being fired from Javascript rather than form?

Or something else? Please halp.

Comment: instead of redirecting from controller you should return the url `return response(['url' => url('/home')], 200);` and in ajax you can do `window.location.href = response.data.url`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XHR requests don't get rendered to the DOM automatically, you will just get the returned html as a variable in the callback in your JavaScript. The redirect you return will only redirect the XHR request, not the actual page in the browser.

If you want to update the page content, you either have to replace the html using JavaScript code, or redirect the page with either [an anchor tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) or [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location).